# Which function grows faster lg( √n ) vs. √ log n

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Which function grows faster :lg( √n ) vs. √ lg n?

When I did the calculations, I get lg (√n) is faster. Is this correct?

Comment: Perhaps looking at a [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%28sqrt%28n%29%29%2F+sqrt%28log%28n%29%29+) would be useful.

Comment: What calculations did you use?  As some have pointed out in the answers, this one can be figured out by recognizing that one term is the square of the other.  [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) is helpful in the general case

Comment: @gcbenison - One is _half_ the square of the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your calculations are correct. lg (√n) = lg (n<sup>1/2</sup>) = lg(n) / 2, which grows as (√ log n)<sup>2</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, I usually graph two functions if I'm unsure which one grows faster.  Normally you'd graph them for values of n that are around your expected range of inputs, but in this case you can see that lg (√n) does grow faster for even small values of n.

[image: Function Graph]

Note: The graph above assumed a base of 2 for **lg** and a base of 10 for **log**.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the bases used for the log functions are irrelevant to big-O calculations.

Comment: I am sorry for typo...both the functions are lg, i.e log base 2...will the answer still be same?

Comment: @user1253637 Yes, the answer would be the same because constants don't matter much for asymptotic growth. `lg( n )` is equal to `log ( n ) / log ( 2 )`. See my answer.

Comment: @user1253637 Yes, the graph would only look slightly different if you change the base.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing

**(1)** lg( √n ) = lg( n ^ (1/2) ) = (1/2) * lg( n )

and

**(2)** √ log n = (√ lg n) / (√ lg 10)

Drop out the constants and that leaves us `lg( n )` and `√ lg n`. Clearly, the first one is growing faster.

As a side note, logarithm of A in base B is equal to the logarithm of A in base X divided by the logarithm of B in base X, where X is a valid value as a logarithm base.